# Dynamic get query in go using pgx

Tags: go, pgx

So I found this: https://betterprogramming.pub/dynamic-sql-query-with-go-8aeedaa02907

it explains how to create a dynamic query for the basic sql package. I would like to do the same thing in pgx but i cant get it to work. Here is my code:

```
func (db *Database) Query(query string, queryParams ...interface{}) {

    rows, _ := db.conn.Query(context.Background(), query)
    defer rows.Close()

    fieldDescriptions := rows.FieldDescriptions()

    var cols []string
    for _, fieldDesc := range fieldDescriptions {
        cols = append(cols, string(fieldDesc.Name))
    }

    row := make([][]byte, len(cols))
    rowPtr := make([]interface{}, len(cols))
    for i := range row {
        rowPtr[i] = &row[i]
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        err := rows.Scan(rowPtr...)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }

        fmt.Println(rowPtr)
    }
}
```

With this I get an error:

```
can't scan into dest[0]: cannot assign 1 into *[]uint8
```

The first item in the row is an id, the first has 1, so its trying to put the int into a *[]uint8, no idea whats going on there.

If i take out row stuff the

```
row := make([][]byte, len(cols))

for i := range row {
    rowPtr[i] = &row[i]
}
```

and just try to read directly to a variadic array of interface{} I would have thought it would read into it, since the Scan takes an interface{}, but i just get nil for everything. Anyone able to shed any light on any of this?

Comment: Did you eventually find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for: https://github.com/DrakoRod/pgx-rowstojson/blob/master/main.go

https://github.com/jackc/pgx/issues/417

Copying the relevant section here for quick reference:

```
// Convert pgx.Rows to json object in []byte format
func PgSqlRowsToJson(rows pgx.Rows) []byte {
    fieldDescriptions := rows.FieldDescriptions()
    var columns []string
    for _, col := range fieldDescriptions {
        columns = append(columns, string(col.Name))
    }
    count := len(columns)
    tableData := make([]map[string]interface{}, 0)
    valuePtrs := make([]interface{}, count)

    for rows.Next() {
        values, _ := rows.Values()
        for i, v := range values {
            valuePtrs[i] = reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(v)).Interface() // allocate pointer to type
        }
        break
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        rows.Scan(valuePtrs...)
        entry := make(map[string]interface{})
        for i, col := range columns {
            var v interface{}
            val := reflect.ValueOf(valuePtrs[i]).Elem().Interface() // dereference pointer
            b, ok := val.([]byte)
            if ok {
                v = string(b)
            } else {
                v = val
            }
            entry[col] = v
        }
        tableData = append(tableData, entry)
    }
    jsonData, _ := json.Marshal(tableData)

    return jsonData
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can "unmarshal" Rows directly into map by just parsing raw values from the response, you don't need to use reflection in this case

```
func sql_to_map(rows pgx.Rows) ([]map[string]any, error) {
    res := []map[string]any{}
    var columns []string
    var columns_amount int
    var values []any
    var err error

    fieldDescriptions := rows.FieldDescriptions()
    columns_amount = len(fieldDescriptions)
    columns = make([]string, columns_amount)

    for i, col := range fieldDescriptions {
        columns[i] = col.Name
    }

    var buf map[string]any
    for rows.Next() {
        buf = make(map[string]any, columns_amount)
        if values, err = rows.Values(); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        for i, v := range values {
            buf[columns[i]] = v
        }
        res = append(res, buf)
    }

    return res, err
}
```

Your select query should look something like this

```
    // ... code
    var rows pgx.Rows
    var err error

    if rows, err = tx.Query(c, query, args...); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    res, err = sql_to_map(rows)
    // ...
```

Tested with this, to select only two fields (const FieldName and const FieldCreatedBy) from table with columns `id, created_at, deleted_at, created_by, name`:

```
func TestSelect(t *testing.T) {
    var res []map[string]any
    var b []byte
    var err error

    store := db.MustConnect(context.Background(), db.Config{
        Dsn:          "postgres://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:5432/postgres",
        Retries:      3,
        RetriesDelay: time.Second,
    })

    q := QuerySelect{
        Fields: []string{FieldName, FieldCreatedBy},
    }
    if res, err = Select(context.Background(), store, &q); err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    if b, err = json.MarshalIndent(res, "", "  "); err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

Got this:

```
[
  {
    "created_by": "boby",
    "name": "ddd"
  },
  {
    "created_by": "boby",
    "name": "dqwdqwqwdqwd"
  },
  {
    "created_by": "boby",
    "name": "test__123123"
  }
]
```